# I'm having a lot of trouble with setInterval and class methods

Tags: javascript

I keep running into bizarre problems. I've been unable to find anything on them after doing some research, so I thought I'd come here to present them.  I have a class which is rather long, but I'll include the relevant bits:

```
class AnimatedSnake {

constructor(canvasId, coordinates) {

    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.direction = 2;

    this.ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext("2d");

    // 0 - .99, describes how far along snake is between coordinates
    this.progress = 0;
}

erase() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.coordinates.length; i++) {
        let c1 = this.coordinates[i][0],
            c2 = this.coordinates[i][1];
        this.ctx.clearRect(c1 * 31, c2 * 31, 31, 31);
    }
}

next() {
    this.progress += 0.01;

    if (this.progress >= 1) {
        this.progress %= 1;

        let nextCoord = this.coordinates[4].slice();
        nextCoord[0] += ((this.direction % 2) * this.direction);
        nextCoord[1] += ((!(this.direction % 2) * (this.direction / 2)));
        this.coordinates.push(nextCoord);
        this.coordinates.shift();
    }
    console.log(this.erase);
    this.erase();
    this.draw();

}

}
```

So far, I can call `AnimatedSnake.next()` indefinitely if I'm doing it manually (i.e. from the console). However, when I put the function in an interval or timeout - `setInterval(AnimatedSnake.next, 100)` - it all of a sudden, on the first run, claims that `AnimatedSnake.erase is not a function`. I tried putting `AnimatedSnake.erase()` directly in the interval, and when I do THAT, for some absurd reason it goes and tells me that it cannot take the length property of `AnimatedSnake.coordinates`, which it claims is undefined. Nowhere in my code to I redefine any of these things. `coordinates` is altered, but it should not be undefined at any point. And `erase` is of course a method that I never change. Does anyone have any insight into why, when these are called with `setInterval` or `setTimeout` weird things happen, but if I call the functions repeatedly (even in a for loop) without the JavaScript timing functions everything works out fine? I'm genuinely stumped.

Comment: When you pass a function to `setIntverval` you loose the context that binds `this` because it just passes a function reference. You can try `setInterval(() => AnimatedSnake.next, 100)` or `setInterval(AnimatedSnake.next.bind(AnimatedSnake), 100)` to keep the correct context for the function call.

Comment: Where's the instance of AnimatedSnake?
They aren't static methods to be used as `AnimatedSnake.next`

Comment: @SajalPreetSingh I have an instance, I just felt I didn't need to explicitly show one to describe my problem.  Don't worry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these two snippets:

```
animatedSnake.next()
```

And:

```
let method = animatedSnake.next;
method();
```

In the first snippet `next` is called as a member of `animatedSnake` object, so `this` within the context of `next` method refers to the `animatedSnake` object.

In the second snippet the `next`  method is *detached* from the object, so `this` no longer refers to the `animatedSnake` instance when the `method` function is invoked. This is how passing a method to another function, like `setInterval` works. You can either use `Function.prototype.bind` method for setting the context manually:

```
setInterval(animatedSnake.next.bind(animatedSnake), 100)
```

or wrap the statement with another function:

```
setInterval(() => animatedSnake.next(), 100)
```

Comment: I'm gonna wrap it in another function - I probably should've thought of that when I was debugging, but I'm still glad I asked the question because I didn't realize that callbacks detached methods from objects/classes.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ElleNolan You are welcome! Since the main topic is the `this` keyword, I think you may find answers of this question useful: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)