# Why calling javascript class method need to be declared in function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I stumbled on this code in [react.js tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
   componentDidMount() {
     this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(),1000);
   }
```

(This componentDidMount() is inside React.Component extension class)

The question is, why I need to bind with () => first?

while if outside class I can just do

```
setInterval(tick,1000)
```

EDIT: in my defense of mark as duplicate question, the provided link of the duplicate question revolves around 'this' keyword. While what I really asked is why should I use arrow function / binding inside the class. Although the answer point to how to use 'this' keyword, the origin and the question is absolutely unique.

Comment: In the tutorial, `tick` is a method within the class. Since it's an **arrow function** (inside the checkInterval), the contextual `this` **is the class one (Clock), NOT the interval function's scope**, hence you're accessing the tick method of the class itself. Outside of the class, you're calling **another** tick method, which is the one declared at the beginning of the tutorial. http://prntscr.com/l7vv49 <-- This is the thick function you're calling, it **can't** be accessed outside of the class in your scenario.

Comment: A related question: [I'm having a lot of trouble with setInterval and class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847856/im-having-a-lot-of-trouble-with-setinterval-and-class-methods/52847962#52847962)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`() =>` is arrow function and the value of `this` inside an arrow function is determined by the surrounding scope. Without the arrow function `this` inside `setInterval` will get a new `scope` so `this.tick` will not work. if you are using the arrow function the `scope` of this will be same for both outside & inside of the `setInterval`